# $C^{1}[0,1]$ is not Banach under $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

This is a curiosity from a reading a text that offered no proof. Why is $(C^{1}[0,1], \|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ not Banach?

Comment: You just need to find a sequence that is Cauchy but not convergent w that metric.

Comment: $C^1([0,1])$ is not closed for the $\|.\|_\infty$ norm. it becomes a Banach space only after you completed $C^1([0,1])$ with the limits of converging sequence (in that case it becomes $L^\infty([0,1])$ )

Comment: I think it rather becomes $C[0,1]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Stone—Weierstrass, any continuous function can be uniformly approximated on $[0,1]$ by a sequence of polynomials.

Take any continuous function in $C^0[0,1] \setminus C^1[0,1]$, i.e. $f$ that is continuous but not continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$. Such functions exist.

Now, take a sequence $(P_n)_n$ of polynomials so that $\lVert f - P_n\rVert_\infty\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$. Such sequence exists by Stone—Weierstrass, and clearly $P_n \in C^1[0,1]$ for all $n$.

But then you have a Cauchy sequence $(P_n)_n$ (since it converges in $C^0[0,1]$ for the $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$ norm) that does not converge *in $C^1[0,1]$* (since $f$ is not $C^1$). So $(C^1[0,1],\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty)$ is not complete.